# Marking a using declaration as [[deprecated]] when it doesn't contain an = (equals sign)

Tags: c++

In C++, I can use `namespace MyNS { using NS::foo; }` to pull `NS::foo` into `MyNS` so I can refer to `MyNS::foo`. I can also be more explicit (but arguably repeat myself, and I can't do it for templates without additional typing) by doing `namespace MyNS { using foo = NS::foo; }` to have the same (exact?) effect.

But if I want to deprecate that `MyNS::foo`, then it seems I have to do `namespace MyNS { using foo [[deprecated]] = NS::foo; }`; I can't just do `namespace MyNS { using [[deprecated]] NS::foo; }`. Is that correct? This is particularly annoying when `foo` is a class template and so the named `using` then needs to be templated to match.

1. At namespace scope, is the `using foo = Other::foo;` form of `using` fundamentally different somehow from `using Other::foo;`?
2. Is there really no way to mark the non-`=` flavor of `using` as `[[deprecated]]`?

I feel like this shines light on a corner of language semantics I haven't questioned carefully. If you have other observations around this, I'd love to hear.

Comment: Which type do you want to be deprecated, the alias, or the original type?

Comment: I want to deprecate the alias. (My real-world application is that I have a header that aliases `nonstd::expected` into `MyNS::Foo::Bar` and I want to move that so the canonical place to find the symbol is `MyNS::expected` but leave `MyNS::Foo::Bar::expected;` marked `[[deprecated]]` for now.

Comment: In summary, you can't really apply an attribute to something that doesn't really exist.

Comment: I think @AdrianMole has the answer I was looking for (and suspecting), assuming they are correct: That without the `=` there isn't really anything to deprecate.

Comment: I may have been "vaguely correct" by accident. My terms were completely wrong and misleading, though.